# how to search ElasticSearch by inner objects

Tags: elasticsearch

consider the following index of `ES`

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": 5,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_source": {
                    "name": "A",
                    "postalCode": {
                        "code": "postcodeA",
                        "validated": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "name": "B",
                    "postalCode": {
                        "code": "postcodeB",
                        "validated": true
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

how do I search for hits with condition:

```
_source.postalCode.validated=true
```

I'm still new and trying to get used to ES.
some of the queries that I've tried are the followings:

```
q=_source.pastalCode.validated=true
q=_source.postalCode.validated
q=_source:postalCode:validated
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either perform a DSL query like so:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
             "filter": {
                 "term": {
                     "postalCode.validated": "true"
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Or using the querystring, as you tried above:

`q=postalCode.validated: true`

You do not need to include the `_source` part.